# Text line contains invalid characters error when changing word-wrapping in longtable

Tags: conversion

I recently received a project which automatically converts a .xml file to Latex and afterwards to  pdf.

The pdf file contains multiple longtables and because there's no word-wrapping inside the tables yet, they're too wide.
[image: Automatically converted latex from html]

Because I couldn't find a way to convert the word-wrapping in html to latex, I made a Powershell script, which replaces one of the 'l' with a 'p{5cm}'.
The script itself worked perfectly fine, but then I started getting these "text contains invalid character" errors:
[image: Invalid character error in logfile]

These errors only happen when I add the 'p{5cm}'. I also noticed that my .aux file is way shorter than before and my .toc file is completely empty.
[image: AuxFile after running selfmade script]

So my questions are:

- Is there another way to add word-wrapping inside columns when converting from html to Latex besides my approach?
- How did it come to this error and how do I fix it?

I'm relatively new to Latex so feel free to give detailed information or links where I can learn about it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My first guess would be that your script did not work perfectly and replaced more than you wanted.

Comment: you have a control character between every letter on that line, how did you edit the file? Tex is not adding these they are in the input file.

Comment: has your file been saved as UTF-16 (so has a 0 byte every second byte)?

Comment: That exactly was my problem. I managed to fix it by adding the encoding parameter in my script. Thank you very much @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log shows a control character every other character. The usual reason for that is the file being saved in UTF-16 which means (for Latin alphabet text) that every other byte is 0 (null).   Try re-saving the file in UTF-8.